# How to reset a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use checkboxes to show items in RecyclerView depending on the checked checkboxes

But I cannot reset the RecyclerView when I uncheck or check. Data is shown over like a pile.

Here is the code in the activity to call the fragment sending checkboxes results to it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    chkMujeres = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkMjr);
    chkHombres = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkHmb);

    chkHombres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                interesHombre=true;
                iniciaFragmentExplora();
            }
            else {interesHombre=false;
            iniciaFragmentExplora();}

        }
    });

    chkMujeres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                interesMujer=true;
                iniciaFragmentExplora();
            }
            else{interesMujer=false;
            iniciaFragmentExplora();}

        }
    });}
```

Here´s the method to start the fragmentExplora which runs the RecyclerView

```
public void iniciaFragmentExplora(){

 fragmentExplora =new FragmentExplora();

 Bundle data = new Bundle();
 data.putBoolean("interesMujer", interesMujer);
 data.putBoolean("interesHombre", interesHombre);
 fragmentExplora.setArguments(data);
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
 add(R.id.frameLayout2,fragmentExplora).commit();
```

}

Here is the code in the fragment "FragmentExplora" which I use to call the adapter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_explora, container, false);


    recyclerView =vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerExplora);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    usersList=new ArrayList<>();


    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    adapter=new AdaptaterDatos(usersList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    CollectionReference collRef = db.collection("Usuarios");


    collRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    usersList.remove(usersList);
                System.out.println(usersList.size());

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()
                         ) {

                        Users user3 = document.toObject(Users.class);

                        Boolean chkMujer=false;
                        Boolean chkHombre=false;

                                chkMujer=getArguments().getBoolean("interesMujer");
                                chkHombre= getArguments().getBoolean("interesHombre");
                        System.out.println("SEXO MUJER"+chkMujer);
                        System.out.println("SEXO HOMBRE"+chkHombre);

                       if(user3.getSexo().equals("mujer")&& chkMujer==true && chkHombre==false) {

                           System.out.println("chicas");

                            usersList.add(user3);
                    }

                      if(user3.getSexo().equals("hombre")&& chkHombre==true && chkMujer==false) {
                            System.out.println("chicos");


                            usersList.add(user3);
                       }

                        if(chkHombre==true && chkMujer==true) {
                            System.out.println("chicos y chias");
                            user3.setCoins(1);
                            usersList.add(user3);
                        }

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //usersList.clear();

            }

            else {}

        }

    });

    return vista;}
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class AdaptaterDatos extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptaterDatos.ViewholderDatos> {

 ArrayList <Users> listUsers;

public AdaptaterDatos(ArrayList<Users> listUsers) {
    this.listUsers = listUsers;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewholderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_explora_vista,null,false);

    return new ViewholderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewholderDatos holder, int position) {


       holder.nombre.setText(listUsers.get(position).getNombre());

       holder.poblacion.setText(listUsers.get(position).getPoblacion());

       holder.edad.setText(calculaEdad(listUsers.get(position).getAnioNac(), listUsers.get(position).getMesNac(),
               listUsers.get(position).getDiaNac()) + " años");





    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

    System.out.println(storageRef.toString());


    StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("images");
    StorageReference imagesRefUser = imagesRef.child(listUsers.get(position).getUserID());
    StorageReference foto1Ref = imagesRefUser.child(listUsers.get(position).getFotoPortada());


    try {
        // showProgressDialog("Download File", "Downloading File...");
        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
        foto1Ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                holder.foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                //dismissProgressDialog();
                //showToast("Download successful!");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                //dismissProgressDialog();
                //  showToast("Download Failed!");
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log.e("Main", "IOE Exception");
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listUsers.size();
}

public class ViewholderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     TextView nombre, edad, poblacion;
     ImageView foto;

    public ViewholderDatos(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUser);
        poblacion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.poblacionUser);
        edad=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edadUser);
        foto=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenPortada);

    }

}
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code you have not called the method setOnCheckedChangeListener() then how will you save the state whether you check the box or not?

Comment: Thank you Sana, I have completed with more code, though I do not use the setOnCheckedChangeListener() the call works, but the refresh of the RecyclerView doesn´t work

Comment: @clementecarbonell please add fragment code to understan ur que

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I have uploaded the rest of code,

Comment: if(user3.getSexo().equals("mujer")&& chkMujer==true && chkHombre==false) before this condition print values on Log this may helps u

Comment: after u get Log ad here so we more clear your que

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // update your RecyclerView 
}});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: it is clear show that when checkbox is checked or unchecked refresh or reset your RecycleView

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(!isChecked)
    {
       //perform your logic here
    }

}});
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you provided some explanation with your code.

Comment: Thank you Ashvin. I edited the question, completing with more code. I don´t use the setOncheckedChanged but the checkboxes works each time I check or uncheck, the problem is that the RecyclerView don´t reset each time I check or uncheck